# Get Integer value from String using VBA

Tags: vba

I'm trying to automate a script using QTP and SAP.

In SAP an order is generated with Document number in status bar as "**Standard PO created under the number 4500290636**"

My challenge is how should I convert take string to an Integer value.

Comment: Does your numeric string always occur at the end, is it always 10 digita?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SAP, I think it is safe to assume that the document number will always have a length of 10 characters. So, you can extract it using the `Right` function, then just convert it using `Val`. Something like this:

```
yourInteger = Val(Right(yourSAPString, 10))
```

Note: in .net, you could use Convert.ToInt32 instead of Val

Answer (score 1):

You could use the split function:

```
Dim strSplit As Variant
Dim yourNumericOut As Variant

    strSplit = Split("Standard PO created under the number 4500290636")

    If IsNumeric(UBound(strSplit)) Then yourNumericOut = --strSplit(UBound(strSplit))
```

Then test for numeric, will allow for many lengths and could change the position of the number in the returned values.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a custom function.

Here is the function:

```
Public Function ExtractNumber(fromString As String) As Double
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With RegEx
        .Pattern = "(\d{1,3},?)+(\.\d{2})?"
        .Global = True
        If .Test(fromString) Then
            ExtractNumber = CDbl(.Execute(fromString)(0))
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Here is the usage example:

```
Sub Example()
    Debug.Print ExtractNumber("Standard PO created under the number 4500290636")
End Sub
```

This code was taken from a similar, more recent answer that has better solutions. See here:
[Excel VBA - Extract numeric value in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365573/excel-vba-extract-numeric-value-in-string)